# Calling JQuery.bind() after a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that works well but I cannot get the idea behind part of it, so any help is appreciated.

In the following function what does the **`bind(this)`** function do at the end of code? I have searched a lot both SO and JQuery documentation but couldn't find any usage like that. All usages of `bind()` try to hook up a function to an event but here bind is called after a function and passed a JQuery object (which is an img tag in this case). Thanks in advance.

```
function refreshCaptcha() {
    var currCaptcha = $('#captcha-div img');

    currCaptcha.animate({
        opacity: 0.3
    }, 300);

    $.getJSON("/captcha.json", function (data) {
        var src = $("#captcha-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(src);
        var newSrc = template(data);
        var srcDom = $(newSrc);

        srcDom.eq(0).css('opacity', 0).load(function() {

            currCaptcha.animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 250, function() {
                $("#captcha-div").html(srcDom);

                $(this).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 250);

            }.bind(this));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I tested myself, but I cannot get the meaning, I mean what does exactly this piece of code do. I want to know which overload of bind() is used here.

Comment: It's not `jQuery.bind()`, it's the standard Javascript `bind()`. See Asad's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind` creates a new function which, when invoked, has its `this` value set to the first argument passed. So in this case, the `animate` callback will have its context set to `srcDom.eq(0)` when invoked.

```
    srcDom.eq(0).css('opacity', 0).load(function() {

        // In here, the value of "this" is srcDom.eq(0)

        currCaptcha.animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 250, function() {
            $("#captcha-div").html(srcDom);

            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 250);

        }.bind(this)); /*When that callback is invoked, all 
                         occurrences of "this" inside it will refer 
                         to srcDom.eq(0)*/

    });
```

More on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: So this is not JQuery's bind but javascript's?